# NTLM Spring Security Exceptions While Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ntlm

I am trying to use NTLM with Spring Security. When I run my index.jsp I am getting exception

```
Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider' defined in 
ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have defined my custom UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider as

```
 <bean id="authenticationProvider"
          class="com.icesoft.icefaces.security.UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider">
        <security:custom-authentication-provider/>
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </bean>
```

How can I resolve this error? As I am struggling with this for the past 2 days.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the userDetailsService bean in your Spring config.

Check out this link about the UserDetailsService interface:

http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/spring-security-basic.html#userDetailsService

Comment: @Joel Arnold, thanks you are right. I missed that config entry in my applicationContext.xml.

Comment: I do have another doubt, do I need to have this entry in my applicationCotext.xml ? or I could use UserDaoImpl to verify authentication details? I am a newbie so kindly excuse my ignorance. Thanks `<security:user-service>
     <security:user name="myuser" password="PASSWORD" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
     <security:user name="administrator" password="PASSWORD" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
   </security:user-service>`

Comment: @Polappan, you can connect to a JDBC datasource with a `security:jdbc-user-service` instead of the `security:user-service`

Checkout this link for an example:

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-security-webapp-spring-config.html

Comment: @Polappan, Sorry, if you've already defined a userDetailsService bean that connects to your DAO you shouldn't need it. Check out this link: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html#d0e2530

Comment: @Joel Arnold this is precisely my doubt is. If I have userDetailsService then in my DAO claass I could connect to database and check the role and username is valid? I probably do not need `<security:user-service>` entry? I am slightly confused at this point.

Comment: @Polappan, correct, as long as you have this line: `<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />` and your `userDetailsService` bean is a class that implements the `UserDetailsService` interface, you don't need anything else.